# Spring boot maven build executed my database operations

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I'm setting up a standalone server..to modify data in the database.
When i finished, i runned maven build and the application started to modify the datas in the database. Really it just started to insert, and update everithing.

```
# PostgreSQL DB - "bar"
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5600/bar
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

# MySQL DB - "foo"
rm.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:5601/foo
rm.datasource.username=
rm.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

That's all i've got in my application properties. I have two config classes as database configurations..and they are contains some more properties:

MySQL

```
properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
properties.put("rm.datasource.driver-class-name", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
properties.put("zeroDateTimeBehavior", "convertToNull");
```

Postgres

```
properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
properties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
```

When i builded my project my application inserted in the postgreSql database.

### Can i just solve it like if i'm building the project..DO NOT insert/update/delete whatever.. in my database?

Comment: I don't get what you're really asking. Either be more precise with your question or provide more code samples; from what you have provided it is just not clear.

Comment: It sounds like your unit test to do this. So, did your unit test connect to the same DB? Because while you running Maven build, it will also run unit test if you don't skip that.

Comment: I did not wrote any JUnit tests.
The maven build just started to do my logic and database operations. So when i clicked on "Maven clean build" it not just thested the methods but executed all my operations.. like if i running the app. Maybe the basic test class (annetated with @SpringBootTest) did that?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse to run Maven build, try to check the checkbox - "Skip tests" then run again.

Comment: @LHCHIN i has solved the problem. please make sure to comment like an answer.. so i can mark it as the solution!

Comment: @csirkeautomata OK, I have posted it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Maven project is generated by either STS (Spring Tool Suite) or Spring Initializr, they are going to automatically create unit test class as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
    }

}
```

The `@SpringBootTest` annotation tells Spring Boot to go and look for a main configuration class (one with `@SpringBootApplication` for instance), and use that to start a Spring application context.

Therefore, if you want to skip unit tests temporally while running Maven build, there are several ways:

- For Eclipse, check the **Skip tests** checkbox.
- Via command line, executing `mvn install -DskipTests` or `mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`.
- Set the **skipTests** property to true of `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>` in your pom.xml.

BTW, you should also check why your application will perform inserting/updating data to database when starts.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I see different possible solutions:

- Skip test with `mvn clean install -DskipTests` or `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`
- Remove all the casses from src/test/**
- In case you will need to proceed with tests in the future, define an in memory database for the test adding:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```

to your pom.xml
For the last solution you may need some initialisation scripts for the DB